# Нету команды на сервере что делать?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cmd, minecraft

нету команды на сервере майнкрафта да и ошибка выдается в консоли Первый код это paper-plugin.yml второй это класс Airdrop а третий это AirdropCommand

```
    name: echolinochka.airdrop 
version: '${project.version}' 
main: echolinochka.airdrop.Airdrop 
api-version: '1.20' 
commands: 
  spawnbarrel: 
    description: Spawns a barrel 
    usage: /spawnbarrel

 package echolinochka.airdrop; 
 
import org.bukkit.Bukkit; 
import org.bukkit.Location; 
import org.bukkit.Material; 
import org.bukkit.World; 
import org.bukkit.block.Block; 
import org.bukkit.command.Command; 
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender; 
import org.bukkit.entity.Player; 
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler; 
import org.bukkit.event.Listener; 
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent; 
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin; 
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable; 
 
import java.util.Random; 
 
public class Airdrop extends JavaPlugin implements Listener { 
 
    private Random random; 
    private World world; 
    private int minX, maxX, minZ, maxZ; 
 
    @Override 
    public void onEnable() { 
        // Регистрируем события 
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this); 
 
        // Получаем мир, в котором будет спавниться бочка 
        world = Bukkit.getWorld("world"); // Замените "world" на имя вашего мира 
 
        // Устанавливаем границы спавна бочки 
        minX = -3000; 
        maxX = 3000; 
        minZ = -3000; 
        maxZ = 3000; 
 
        // Создаем экземпляр класса Random 
        random = new Random(); 
 
        // Запускаем задачу спавна бочки каждые 10 секунд 
        new BukkitRunnable() { 
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                spawnBarrel(); 
            } 
        }.runTaskTimer(this, 0, 2000); // 10 секунд = 200 тиков 
 
        // Регистрируем команду 
        getCommand("spawnbarrel").setExecutor(new AirdropCommand(this)); 
    } 
 
    @Override 
    public void onDisable() { 
        // Отменяем все запущенные задачи при выключении плагина 
        Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTasks(this); 
    } 
 
    @EventHandler 
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) { 
        Player player = event.getPlayer(); 
        player.sendMessage("Добро пожаловать на сервер!"); 
    } 
 
    public void spawnBarrel() { 
        // Генерируем случайные координаты для спавна бочки 
        int x = random.nextInt(maxX - minX + 1) + minX; 
        int z = random.nextInt(maxZ - minZ + 1) + minZ; 
        int y = world.getHighestBlockYAt(x, z) + 2; 
 
        // Создаем локацию для спавна бочки 
        Location location = new Location(world, x, y, z); 
 
        // Создаем блок бочки 
        Block barrelBlock = location.getBlock(); 
        barrelBlock.setType(Material.BARREL); 
 
        // Отправляем координаты бочки в чат 
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Бочка спавнится на координатах: X: " + x + ", Y: " + y + ", Z: " + z); 
    } 
}
package echolinochka.airdrop; 
 
import org.bukkit.command.Command; 
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor; 
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender; 
 
public class AirdropCommand implements CommandExecutor { 
 
    private Airdrop plugin; 
 
    public AirdropCommand(Airdrop plugin) { 
        this.plugin = plugin; 
    } 
 
    @Override 
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) { 
        if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawnbarrel")) { 
            plugin.spawnBarrel(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
}
а вот ошибка в консоли Error occurred while enabling echolinochka.airdrop v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.setExecutor(org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor)" because the return value of "echolinochka.airdrop.Airdrop.getCommand(String)" is null
at echolinochka.airdrop.Airdrop.onEnable(Airdrop.java:51) ~[airdrop-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:281) ~[paper-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.enablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:190) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.enablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:104) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:507) ~[paper-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:637) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:548) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld0(MinecraftServer.java:671) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadLevel(MinecraftServer.java:431) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:308) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1130) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:319) ~[paper-1.20.4.jar:git-Paper-399]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)